# Github - Untracked Files

Tags: github

I'm trying to commit my project using `git commit -m "First."`. But throw this error, remembering that I wrote `git init`.

[image]

Comment: Execute "git add ." beforehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other version control systems simply commit whatever files have been changed. Git is different. You must first build the commit by adding them to the staging area with `git add`. Then you `git commit` what has been added. This allows you to do some very powerful things, like split big changes into multiple commits.

For the above, add everything with `git add .` then you can commit. Though you probably want to add .vscode, tmp/, *.lock and any other temporary files and directories to your .gitignore file.

For more, please read [Git Basics - Recording Changes to the Repository](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository).